# A fatal error when viewing a 'draft' post in wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, themes

The fatal error appears when I wish to preview a drafted post. I have no idea what could have possibly started this error. I will post below the entire code I see.

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on
>   boolean in
>   /homepages/7/d680526825/htdocs/clickandbuilds/nouveautycoon/wp-content/plugins/td-cloud-library/state/single/tdb_state_single.php:777
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /homepages/7/d680526825/htdocs/clickandbuilds/nouveautycoon/wp-content/plugins/td-cloud-library/shortcodes/single/tdb_single_date.php(130):
>   tdb_state_single->{closure}() #1
>   /homepages/7/d680526825/htdocs/clickandbuilds/nouveautycoon/wp-content/plugins/td-cloud-library/shortcodes/single/tdb_single_date.php(130):
>   Closure->__invoke() #2
>   /homepages/7/d680526825/htdocs/clickandbuilds/nouveautycoon/wp-content/plugins/td-composer/legacy/common/wp_booster/td_global_blocks.php(27):
>   tdb_single_date->render(Array, '') #3
>   /homepages/7/d680526825/htdocs/clickandbuilds/nouveautycoon/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(325):
>   td_global_blocks::proxy_function(Array, '', 'tdb_single_date') #4
>   [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #5
>   /homepages/7/d680526825/htdocs/clickandbuilds/nouveautycoon/wp-includes/shortcodes.php
>   in
>   /homepages/7/d680526825/htdocs/clickandbuilds/nouveautycoon/wp-content/plugins/td-cloud-library/state/single/tdb_state_single.php
>   on line 777 There has been a critical error on your website.
>
> Learn more about debugging in WordPress.

Any help, will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

P.S. - the theme used is called newspaper and is by tagdiv.
https://nouveautycoon.comis the website in question

Comment: Remove TD-Cloud Plugin?

Comment: I have tried this and it seemed to have fixed the problem but it also ends up creating another one. Most of the theme's elements relies heavily on that plugin so when it's removed it affects large areas of the website.

Comment: Okay, I seem to have figured out the problem and it now appears to be working. Cheers for pointing out the TDCloud Plugin - i had been searching for hours. :)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the TDCloud Plugin Plugin should do the job. Or downloading a fresh copy and overwrite the files.